# Convergence, link with Sierpinski triangle

Tags: general-topology

[image: construction of a Sierpinski triangle]

This image shows the construction of the Sierpinski triangle up to the fourth iteration. My question is simple.

If I construct a sequence of subsets of the triangle in this way :

$\mathcal{E}_{0}=\emptyset$

$\mathcal{E}_{i}$ is the union of the white closed subsets in the triangle at the i-th iteration of the Sierpinski triangle construction.

I know that the k-th element of this sequence is the closed complementary of the approximation of the Sierpinski triangle and that this sequence is increasing and bounded so i suppose that it converges.

So I would like to know if this sequence tends to the triangle or tends to the triangle difference ``something''.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps a definition is needed for "tends to".  Sequence $\mathcal E_n$ tends to the filled-in triangle $\mathcal T$ in the Hausdorff metric.  Every point of $\mathcal T$ is arbitrarily close to some point of $\mathcal E_n$ for large enough $n$.  (And every point of $\mathcal E_n$ is already in $\mathcal T$.)

Comment: @ GEdgar. Yep, it is what about i'm thinking when I wrote the question, for every point $x\in\mathcal{T}$, i can find a $n_{0}$ such that $x\in\mathcal{E}_{n_{0}}$ but i'm not enough skilled to precise the topology or a correct definition for ``tends to''